# Retrieve data within a SQL JSON Object, and array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have data  formatted in the following way in a column named value:

{
  "data" : [
    "AVM": "1,000", 
    "location": "CA"
  ]
}

I am trying to write a simple SQL query to retrieve the AVM values for the entire dataset stored in a postgresql database, which is a couple thousand records.

Does anyone know an elegant solution to be able to do this?

select p."value" -> 'data'
from table as p;

But not able to dig into the array to retrieve the AVM values.

Comment: Its not a Proper JSON

Comment: Would you know how to access based on this format? @AkhileshMishra

Comment: Where are the values coming from? It looks like it could be YAML(https://yaml.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you try the value as written:

```
select '{ data: [ "AVM": "1,000", "location": "CA" ] }'::json;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select '{ data: [ "AVM": "1,000", "location": "CA" ] }'::jso...
```

Assuming the data is YAML you could pull it out of the database and use a YAML parser to get the data. An example in Python(https://pyyaml.org/):

```
import yaml
y_str = '{ "data" : [ "AVM": "1,000", "location": "CA" ] }' 
y_dict = yaml.safe_load(y_str)  
y_dict                                                                                                                                                                     
{'data': [{'AVM': '1,000'}, {'location': 'CA'}]}
y_dict["data"][0]["AVM"]                                                                                                                                                   
'1,000'
```

If you have `plpythonu or plpython3u` installed in database you could write a function that did the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I am testing these out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the query using the following in a Postgre Database:

select (t.value -> 'data' ->> 0)::json -> 'AVM' as "AVM"
from table as t;

The general format for pseudo code.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a query similar to this

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.data.AMV') 
FROM {tableName}
```

---

You can also filter data:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.data.AMV') 
FROM {tableName}
WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.data.location') = 'CA'
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#QUERY)

Comment: Thank you, I am testing these out.

Comment: Two problems with this first, the string is not valid JSON. Second, that function is for MS SQL Server not Postgresql. If you want to do similar things in Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH